# what's the meaning of ENTRY statement in entry.S in Linux kernel for i386

Tags: linux, assembly, kernel, i386

for example in entry.S

```
ENTRY(ret_from_fork)
    pushl %eax
    call schedule_tail
    GET_THREAD_INFO(%ebp)
    popl %eax
    jmp syscall_exit
```

so what's the syntax of ENTRY in as language?
I think all the directive of as is start with . and the ENTRY also doesn't look like a macro 
can anyone tell me about the ENTRY is what? if it is defined in Linux source code could anyone indicate the location or if it is a syntax in as can someone tell me where i can find the specific description of this use! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you say it doesn't look like a macro, because that's exactly how macros look like. And indeed it is a macro defined in [include/linux/linkage.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/linkage.h?id=refs/tags/v3.14-rc3#n81) as follows:

```c
#ifndef ENTRY
#define ENTRY(name) \
    .globl name ASM_NL \
    ALIGN ASM_NL \
    name:
#endif
```

Comment: the reason i think it is not an macro is i think in assembly there is no preprocessing, but .S suffix is tell the gcc to using preprocessing   before compiling the assembly which is not support in as

Answer (score 1):

I think that's an assembler directive .
As per my knowledge ENTRY assembler directive is used when we use Keil assembler.
That's actually the entry point of a application.

The way we have _start or _main entry point in assembly code when we use GNU assembler.